# jackson auto map/deserialize json with unique property

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

How can i use jackson annotations to automap json to my object. I have nested pojo's for each part of the json but the property name im receiving is a unique id for each object. What should be in the Employees class that will be actually mapping the id and object with names. I have a class below:

```
public class Company {
  @JsonProperty("employees")
  private Employees employees;
  //getters setters
}




   "Employees": {
    "1355075": {
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastName": "doe"
     },

     "1224423": {
        "firstName": "frank",
        "lastName": "stevens"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON example seems to miss a `{` at the very beginning.
And there is an spelling mismatch between your
Java class (`@JsonProperty("employees")`)
and your JSON example (`"Employees"`).

In your JSON example, the part after `"Employees":`
has the form of a JSON object, mapping strings (the unique ids)
to objects (each with a firstName and lastName).
Now Jackson comes with a generic [`MapDeserializer`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/MapDeserializer.html) which can
deserialize anything looking like a JSON object to a Java `Map`.
Therefore your `Company` class should simply have something like this:

```
     @JsonProperty("Employees")
     private Map<String, Employee> employees;
```

You will also need to write an `Employee` class with
two String properties named `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: Thank you, the map works, I didn’t know if it would be able to map since it didn’t know the property name.

Comment: @AryaAtighehchian Glad I could help. If the answer solved your problem you may consider to accept it. See also [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).